# I use LWJGL and when I use glfwCreateWindow it stuck my code

Tags: java, lwjgl

I am new to LWJGL and not a pro at Java, but I want to learn how to create a game.
I use a Mac. And when I run my code, it get stuck at glfwCreateWindow, I watched a lot of tutorial but I can't fix it.

Here is the code that make problems:

```
private void init() {
        if(!glfwInit()) {
            System.err.println("ERROR: can't initialize GLFW");
        }
        
        glfwInit();
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GLFW_FALSE);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VISIBLE, GLFW_FALSE);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
        
        windowID = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "Window", 0, 0);
        glfwMakeContextCurrent(windowID);
        GL.createCapabilities();
        glfwShowWindow(windowID);
    }
```

And here is all my code:

```
    
    private static Window instance = null;
    
    private long windowID;
    
    private Window() {}
    
    public static Window get() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new Window();
        }
        return instance;
    }
    
    public void run() {
        init();
        loop();
    }
    
    private void init() {
        if(!glfwInit()) {
            System.err.println("ERROR: can't initialize GLFW");
        }
        
        glfwInit();
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GLFW_FALSE);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VISIBLE, GLFW_FALSE);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
        
        windowID = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "Window", 0, 0);
        glfwMakeContextCurrent(windowID);
        GL.createCapabilities();
        glfwShowWindow(windowID);
    }
    
    private void loop() {
        while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(windowID)) {
            glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
            glfwSwapBuffers(windowID);
            glfwPollEvents();
        }
    }
}
```

I hope someone can help me (an I am new to Stackoverflow too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just need to put
`-XstartOnFirstThread` in the VM argument and it work.